# PHP inside Image Tag

Tags: php, html

I would like to insert PHP variables inside image tag. Can you please help me in writing the code with escape characters

```
    <img src='"Images/"<?$j_$i?>.jpg'/>
```

Comment: `printf('<img src="Images/%s_%s.jpg" />', $j, $i);`

Answer (score 1):

You should only use `<?php`

```
<img src='Images/<?php echo $j.'_'.$i; ?>.jpg'/>
```

It's not beautiful,but it's always supported by server

Comment: Since 5.4, `<?=` is *always* supported.

Comment: Well, it's not *always* 5.4

Comment: Not saying you're wrong, but statements such as these have a (relatively early) expiry date.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually *output* something.

Use `<?=` instead of `<?`.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
 <img src='"Images/"<?$j_$i?>.jpg'/>
```

To:

```
 <img src='Images/.<?php echo $j .'_'. $i;?>.jpg'/>
```